# How to merge 2 columns to one in TextMate?

Tags: textmate, merge, textwrangler

Anyone knows how would one merge such list as

```
item 1  item 2
item 3  item 4
```

to

```
item 1 
item 2 
item 3 
item 4
```

in TextMate or TextWrangler?

Answer (score 1):

How are the columns separated? By a `\t`? If so, you just want to replace this with a newline. <sub>If they aren't separated by a tab, the procedure is the same – just copy the column separator, whatever it is. Two spaces for example should work just fine, as will a `,` when working witha CSV.</sub>

```
item 1  item 2
item 3  item 4
```

The procedure's fairly easy:

- Copy the tab character from the text field with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (it might help to have *View → Show Invisibles* enabled)

  [image]
- Open a search/replace window with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
- Paste the copied tab character into the "Find" field with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.
- In the "Replace" field, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a new line.

It'll look like this (yes, you can't see anything, but you can select the contents to see everything's there).

[image]

Then, click "Replace All". Result:

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
```

As [@romainl](https://superuser.com/users/60075/) points out, it's also possible to use Regular Expressions for that. If you know the separator is Tab (`\t`), just check "Regular expression" and enter `\t` for "Find" and `\n` for "Replace.

[image]

Comment: One could also check the "Regular Expression" checkbox and type `\t` in the "Find:" textfield and `\n` in the "Replace:" textfield.

Comment: Yup, didn't want to include it at first because with Regular expressions you'd have to read up what to use if your separator is *not* `\t`. I added that to the answer though, thanks for pointing out.